# nginx: act as an in line reverse proxy (listen on one nic, servers on other nic...)

Tags: nginx

I have used nginx with great success with the nginx host using a single nic.

The question here is: How to handle with the nginx host will have two nics, one on the 'public' network (visible through firewall to public), and one on the 'dmz' network (web hosts that cannot be seen on public).

E.g.

Centos v6.x box running nginx, has 3 nics, on networks: A, B, and C

Public IP A --> firewalled to private IP on network A
Web servers on network C and network D

Is the following the correct way to have nginx bind to the appro nics?

```
upstream apachephp  {
      server <host on network B>:80; 
      server <host on network C>:80;
}

server {
    listen <address on network A>:80;
  ...
```

Comment: That seems fine. Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton No problem (haven't set it up yet), but also was not able to find docs discussing this kind of set up. Ergo the question.